# Performance of accessing the same getter twice in a statement

Tags: dart, micro-optimization

Lets say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass{
  List<List<String>> get myProperty{
    return some_complex_logic_that_returns_a_list_list_string();
  }
}
```

Now I want to use `MyClass.myPropery` twice in the same statement, for example:

```
  MyClass myClass = MyClass();
  String s = myClass.myProperty.isNotEmpty ? myClass.myProperty[0][0] : '';
```

But because I happen to know that the internals of the `myProperty` getter are rather complex, my gut instinct is to instead do:

```
  MyClass myClass = MyClass();
  final list = myClass.myProperty;
  String s = list.isNotEmpty ? list[0][0] : '';
```

Of course, someone who has no information about the internals of `myPropery` would probably not do that. So what I'm wondering is - does assigning `myProperty` to a local variable actually improve performance, or does the compiler cache/reuse the result of a getter if it's used multiple times in the same statement?

Comment: A compiler won't cache the result of a call unless it knows the result cannot have changed between calls. We cannot know that without analyzing the "complex logic" of the property. Then even if we conclude it's safe to cache, we could be wrong (unless we're experts on Dart semantics) or we might know something the compiler can't determine for itself. In other words, I believe you can't count on Dart caching these values for you — unless perhaps the logic is not complex enough to make caching that worthwhile in the first place.

Comment: If you want to cache the result you could use a `late final` variabile eg: `late final List<List<String>> myProperty = some_complex_logic_that_returns_a_list_list_string();`